# Loading a bigquery dataset into kaggle

Tags: google-bigquery, kaggle

I am trying to download a dataset from bigquery public dataset into kaggle.

`bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_2017`

I tried the following code,

```
import bq_helper
from bq_helper import BigQueryHelper

bq_assistant = BigQueryHelper("bigquery-public-data", "ghcn_d")
QUERY = "SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_2017`"
df = bq_assistant.query_to_pandas("SELECT FROM `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_2017`")
```

But I get the following error,

```
Unauthenticated: 401 Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

I can see that `bq_assistant.list_tables()` actually lists all the tables in the database, and you can see that `ghcnd_2017` is one of the tables. If you try `bq_assistant.head('ghcnd_2017')`,you can see the head of the table.

So instead, I tried to make a googlecloud account and download my credentials.

```
!pip install google-cloud-bigquery-storage
from google.cloud import bigquery

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '../input/googlecloud/creds.json'

client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset("ghcn_d", project="bigquery-public-data")
dataset = client.get_dataset(dataset_ref)

table_ref = dataset_ref.table("ghcnd_2017")
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
df = client.list_rows(table).to_dataframe()
```

But i get this error again...

```
Unauthenticated: 401 Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

How do I authenticate my google cloud account ? Or is there a way I can use the bq_assistant to download my dataset? Why can I only see the head of the table and not the whole table?

Comment: How do you get the credential? What permission do you assign to your credential? I use the same code with my credential and everything works well. You can follow this [guide](https://jingsblog.com/2018/11/27/connect-your-jupyter-notebook-to-the-bigquery/) to connect to BQ from python code.

Comment: I meant with kaggle not my computer

Comment: Maybe your problem is your credential path? Could you use the python code to read the content of the credential with your config path '../input/googlecloud/creds.json'? Of course, test with your credential in locally first.

Comment: i tried it, it reads fine